# How to get counts from various joins to the same table in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count

I have two tables, blogs and posts, with the expected relationship between them. Posts can be published or draft. I want to select all blogs with the counts of published and draft posts. How can I do it?

I tried this query:

```
SELECT blogs.*,
       COUNT(published_posts.*) AS published_post_count,
       COUNT(draft_posts.*) AS draft_post_count
FROM blogs
JOIN posts AS published_posts ON published_posts.blog_id=blogs.id AND 
                                 published_posts.state = "published"
JOIN posts AS draft_posts ON draft_posts.blog_id=blogs.id AND 
                             draft_posts.state = "draft"
GROUP BY blogs.id
```

but I end up with the same number for both published_post_count and draft_post_count and being wrong for both.

Then I got desperate and trie:

```
SELECT blogs.*,
       COUNT(published_posts.*) AS published_post_count,
       COUNT(draft_posts.*) AS draft_post_count
FROM blogs
JOIN (SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.state="published") AS published_posts
     ON published_posts.blog_id=blogs.id 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.state="draft") AS draft_posts
     ON draft_posts.blog_id=blogs.id
GROUP BY blogs.id
```

but in both cases I had the same wrong results.

What's the proper way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just interested in the `COUNT` and you are also `JOIN`ing the tables. So there has to be one or more `post` that has been `published` and one or more that is `draft`. So maybe this will help you:

```
SELECT blogs.*,
       (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM posts
            WHERE posts.blog_id=blogs.id
            AND posts.state = "published"
       ) AS published_post_count,
       (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM posts
            WHERE posts.blog_id=blogs.id
            AND posts.state = "draft"
       ) AS draft_post_count,
FROM blogs
```

Comment: This works. But isn't this the same as running many queries? (N+1)

Comment: No. Because it is sub queries that depends on the outer queries. And doing COUNT(*) is not that ineffective.

Comment: If you are fine with the answer you might consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You might count different states and join back to blogs:

```
SELECT blogs.*, p.published_post_count, p.draft_post_count
FROM blogs
JOIN 
(
  SELECT posts.blog_id,
         SUM(case when posts.state = 'published' then 1 end) 
             AS published_post_count,
         SUM(case when posts.state = 'draft' then 1 end) 
             AS draft_post_count
    FROM posts
   GROUP BY blog_id
) p
ON p.blog_id=blogs.id
```

Comment: On large tables I would expect this to be much faster than the correlated subqueries approach, although it would be worth testing both to confirm.  I was surprised that the CASE predicates didn't have "else 0" clauses, but a quick test suggests that it works just fine without them.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
GROUP BY blogs.id,published_posts.[theKeyOfThisTable],draft_posts.[theKeyOfThisTable]
```

as you should contain the columns  of the "select" at your "group by" clause